Problemas al descagar un pdf en php y ajax
vuelvo de nuevo aquí, tengo un problema con un programa que estoy realizando, creamos un pdf con datos de un usuario y el nombre de un archivo. Ese pdf se crea por un botón que hace su post en ajax y manda los datos a un php, el problema es que no puedo descargarlo o visualizarlo.
Adjunto código del php donde se crea el pdf.
'require 'conexion.php';
require '../fpdf/fpdf.php';

$dato = array();
$nombreP = $_POST['nombreP'];
$userP = $_POST['usuarioP'];
$correoP = $_POST['correoP'];
$unidadA = $_POST['unidadP'];
$areaA = $_POST['areaP'];
$fechaD = $_POST['fechaP']; $fechaDN = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fechaD));
$horaD = $_POST['horaP'];
$doc = $_POST['archivoP'];

$queryD = "INSERT INTO prestamos(nombreP, userP, correoP, archivo, area, unidad, fecha, hora) VALUES ('".$nombreP."','".$userP."','".$correoP."','".$doc."',".$areaA.",".$unidadA.",'".$fechaDN."','".$horaD."')";
$resD = $con->query($queryD);

if($resD){
    $queryDatos = "SELECT nombreP, userP, correoP, fecha, hora, areas.unidad_responsable AS unidadRP, areas.descripcion AS descAP, DATE_ADD(fecha, INTERVAL 3 DAY) AS fechaDev FROM prestamos 
    INNER JOIN areas ON areas.unidad=prestamos.unidad AND areas.id_area=prestamos.area AND fecha='".$fechaDN."' AND hora='".$horaD."';";
    $resDA = $con->query($queryDatos);

    $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','Letter');
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->Image('../img/spf.png' , 8 ,8, 80 , 22,'png');
    $pdf->Ln(35);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(192, 192, 192, 1);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
    $pdf->Cell(190,8,utf8_decode('Vale de Préstamo'),1,1,'C',True);

    while($rowDA = $resDA->fetch_assoc()){
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
        $pdf->Cell(190,8,utf8_decode('Nombre del solicitante: '.$rowDA['nombreP']),1,1);
        $pdf->Cell(190,8,utf8_decode('Usuario del solicitante: '.$rowDA['userP']),1,1);
        $pdf->Cell(190,8,utf8_decode('Correo del solicitante: '.$rowDA['correoP']),1,1);
        $pdf->Ln();
    
        $pdf->Cell(190,8,utf8_decode('Unidad de Adscripción: '.$rowDA['unidadRP']),1,1);
        $pdf->Cell(190,8,utf8_decode('Área de Adscripción: '.$rowDA['descAP']),1,1);
        $pdf->Ln();
    
        $pdf->Cell(95,8,utf8_decode('Fecha de préstamo: '.$rowDA['fecha']),1);
        $pdf->Cell(95,8,utf8_decode('Hora de préstamo: '.$rowDA['hora']),1,1);
        $pdf->Cell(190,8,utf8_decode('Fecha de devolución: '.$rowDA['fechaDev']),1,1);
        $pdf->Ln();
    
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $pdf->Cell(190,5,utf8_decode('* Este documento avala el trámite de préstamo, por lo que debera presentarlo en cuanto se le entregue el Documento Oficial,'),0,1);
        $pdf->Cell(190,5,utf8_decode('  y así mismo cuando se devuelva.'),0,1);
        $pdf->Ln(100);
    
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
        $pdf->Cell(190,5,utf8_decode('Recibí Documento Oficial original'),0,1,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(190,5,utf8_decode($rowDA['nombreP']),0,1,'C');
    }
    $pdf->Output('S','valePrestamo.pdf');
    $dato[] = ['error'=>true, 'pdf'=>$pdf];
    print_r($dato);
    /*ob_end_clean();
    crearpdf($fechaDN, $horaD);*/
}else{
    echo $dato[] = ['error'=>false];
}'

el pdf lo realizo con fpdf, sé que para forzar a descargarlo se debe colocar una 'D' en vez de una 'S' pero no me funciona y quise mandarlo al ajax con un código que encontré también pero de igual forma no me aparece, cuando intento algo nuevo solo salen números raros.

Espero puedan ayudarme, se los agradecería demasiado. También adjunto el codigo de ajax.
$.ajax({
                url: 'base/prestarD.php',
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                data: $("#fprestamo").serialize()
            }).done(function(respD){
                console.log(respD);
                if(respD.error){
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Trámite de préstamo exitoso',
                        text: 'En un momento se descargará tu vale de préstamo',
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "Aceptar",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#4169E1",
                        showCloseButton: false,
                    }).then(()=>{
                        console.log('ENTRE AL THEN');
                        var blob = new Blob([respD.pdf]);
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        link.save = 'valePrestamo.pdf';
                        link.click();
                        //location.href = "busqueda.php";
                    });

Edición:
Muchas gracias por el aporte, no he podido comprobar si funciona ya que ahora el servidor me arroja como una respuesta falsa

Adjunto la fotografía, entonces si es falsa la respuesta obviamente no los descarga el archivo, no sé si la salida de mis datos son incorrectos, así es la salida que le doy, incluso probé con json_encode y no me arroja nada:
$pdf->Output('S','valePrestamo.pdf');

    var_dump(array('error'=>true, 'pdf'=>$pdf));

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

si ya puedes mostrar el PDF en javascript con esto:
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'valePrestamo.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);

ya deberas poder descargarlo, aqui estamos convirtiendo el blob a una url, estamos asignandolo a un elemento a y luego simulamos un click, una vez ejecutado el click removemos el elemento ... no es necesarios remover si no quieres ...

Ya pude lograrlo, solo que no puedo abrir el archivo que me descarga, me dice que se decodificó mal. Pero muchas gracias por el aporte.

@Stephane ok bueno si alguna respuesta te ayudo a solucionar tu problema puedes marcarla como resuelta y listo, saludos.
